# How to do IF/ELSE conditions inside LOOP in golang templates?

Tags: go, go-templates

I tried to do this test to figure out how to make conditions like this:

```
<h1>Country Index</h1>

<style>
.odd{
    background: orange;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.even{
    background: rgb(0, 121, 235);
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
</style>

<ul>
    {{ range $index, $item := .Tee }}
        {{ if $index % 2 == 0 }}
            <li class="even">{{ $index }} - {{ $item }}</li>
        {{ else }}
            <li class="odd">{{ $index }} - {{ $item }}</li>
        {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
</ul>
```

I got this error "**unexpected "%" in operand**".

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: To solve what? What issue did you run into?

Comment: sorry @Adrian I forget, I update the issue now, hahaha :)

Comment: I don't think you can perform arithmetic in templates, you'd have to write a user function. Or you could get rid of all the template logic and [just do it in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: @Adrian Is there any alternative template library in **golang** make me to do these stuff?

Comment: Recommendations for third-party libraries are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is it illegal here for the recommendations, even it could be very helpful!

Comment: I guess you can try opening an issue on the GitHub page. This one looks like your case, but complaining for the `=` operand. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10608

Comment: It doesn't matter how helpful you might find a recommendation. [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks guys for this enlightenment. <3

Comment: I created a new issue here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use operators like +, -, *, /, or % in templates, unfortunately. Instead you have to write custom functions and use a funcMap to bring them into your template.

Here's an example on the Go Playground that detects even integers applied to a slightly modified version of your template text.

https://play.golang.org/p/LWEhE_TI31o

Answer (score 2):

You can create bool helper variable and change its state every iteration.

```html
{{$odd := true}}
{{range $data := .Tee}}
   {{if $odd}}
      <p>action for odd.</p>
   {{else}}
      <p>action for not odd.</p>
   {{end}}
{{$odd = not $odd}}
{{end}}
```